# How to avoid Swift warning "Instance method 'willChangeValue' is unavailable from asynchronous contexts; "

Tags: swift, async-await, task

How can I call "willChangeValue" when using swift Task/await without the following warning showing up?

*Instance method 'willChangeValue' is unavailable from asynchronous contexts; Only notify of changes to a key in a synchronous context. Notifying changes across suspension points has undefined behavior.; this is an error in Swift 6*

```
    @objc dynamic var localFilesTitle: String {
        get {
            return "\(localTitle)(\(localFiles.count))"
        }
        set {
            
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        Task {
            await initialise()
            
            self.isInitialised = true
            
            let local = await self.getLocalFiles()
            
            DebugLog("Found \(local.count) local files")
            
            for file in local.filter({!$0.isDirectory}) {
                DebugLog(" \(file.name),\(file.size),\(file.modifiedDate)")
            }
            
            self.willChangeValue(forKey: "localFilesTitle")
            self.localFiles.append(contentsOf: local.filter({!$0.isDirectory}))
            self.didChangeValue(forKey: "localFilesTitle")
            
//            let remote = await self.getRemoteFiles()
//            
//            self.awsFiles = remote
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: I recommend either showing the whole code necessary for this example/issue, like what is exactly `initialise()`? or removing the lines that are not relevant for your question so that is easier to analyse and discuss.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason why you’re using KVO at all? Sure, if you are integrating with legacy code or Objective-C, KVO is fine, but there are more modern, swiftier, observing patterns.

Comment: @Rob - yes KVO required for triggering Interface builder bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code should be called on the main actor, so you should wrap it like this:

```swift
await MainActor.run { 
    self.willChangeValue(forKey: "localFilesTitle")
    self.localFiles.append(contentsOf: local.filter({!$0.isDirectory}))
    self.didChangeValue(forKey: "localFilesTitle")  
}
```

Comment: Thanks - seems I can only accept one answer but both your and Rob's answers are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I avoid patterns where I have to call `willChangeValue` and `didChangeValue` manually. The `dynamic` stored properties can do this for us.

So, there are a few additional approaches, in addition to those already discussed:

1. I would forego the computed property, make it a simple stored property, and `dynamic` will take care of all the necessary KVO notifications for me.

   ```swift
   class ViewController: NSViewController { // or UIViewController, as appropriate

       @objc dynamic var localFilesTitle: String = ""

       var localTitle: String = ""

       var localFiles: [FileWrapper] = [] {
           didSet {
               localFilesTitle = "\(localTitle) (\(localFiles.count))"
           }
       }

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           Task {
               localTitle = "Foo"
               let localDirectories = await self.getLocalFiles()
                   .filter { $0.isDirectory }

               localFiles.append(contentsOf: localDirectories)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. The other approach is to make `localFiles` a `dynamic` property, as well, and use [`keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1414299-keypathsforvaluesaffectingvalue) to tell the KVO system that the `localFilesTitle` is affected automatically by `localFiles`:

   ```swift
   class ViewController: NSViewController {

       @objc dynamic var localFilesTitle: String { "\(localTitle) (\(localFiles.count))" }

       var localTitle: String = ""

       @objc dynamic var localFiles: [FileWrapper] = []

       override func viewDidLoad() { 
           // same as above ...
       }

       override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
           guard key == #keyPath(localFilesTitle) else {
               return super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key)
           }

           return [#keyPath(localFiles)]
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks - it seems there are multiple options.  #2 is probably the one that seems the 'cleanest'.

Comment: I am going to accept jrtuton's answer - just because it provides the MainActor.run{} explanation.  Strictly speaking I think your #2 is probably more 'correct'.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution by [jrturton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74653698/4691224) works, but if you want to avoid having even more nested blocks you can also delegate to a `MainActor` `async` method like this:

Updated with feedback from jrturton.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Task {
        /*
         async code here
        */

        await myMethod()
    }      
}

@MainActor private func myMethod() {
    willChangeValue(forKey: "localFilesTitle")
    localFiles.append(contentsOf: local.filter({!$0.isDirectory}))
    didChangeValue(forKey: "localFilesTitle")
}
```

Comment: This code still generates the warning, you are still calling the methods from an asynchronous context.

Comment: @jrturton Thanks for the feedback, updated accordingly with your well placed observation.